# ALAssetsLibrary Get Photos At Location

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, alassetslibrary

The following code successfully checks the EXIF data for all the photos in a user's library, and passes to a completion block an array of the photos that were taken in close geographic proximity to a given location, as well as the `NSDate` of the most recent photo taken at that location.

```
- (void)getPhotosAtLocation:(CLLocation *)location withCompletionBlock:(void (^)(NSError *, NSDate *, NSMutableArray *))completionBlock {
    NSMutableArray *photos = [NSMutableArray array];
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    __block NSDate *latestDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
    [assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            if (result) {
                ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [result defaultRepresentation];
                NSDictionary *imageMetadata = [representation metadata];
                NSLog(@"%@", imageMetadata);
                //analyze location
                if ([imageMetadata objectForKey:@"{GPS}"]) {
                    double latitude = [[[imageMetadata objectForKey:@"{GPS}"] objectForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue];
                    if ([[[imageMetadata objectForKey:@"{GPS}"] objectForKey:@"LatitudeRef"] isEqualToString:@"S"])
                        latitude *= -1;
                    double longitude = [[[imageMetadata objectForKey:@"{GPS}"] objectForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue];
                    if ([[[imageMetadata objectForKey:@"{GPS}"] objectForKey:@"LongitudeRef"] isEqualToString:@"W"])
                        longitude *= -1;
                    if (fabs(location.coordinate.latitude - latitude) <= 0.0005 && fabs(location.coordinate.longitude - longitude) <= 0.0005)
                        [photos addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[result thumbnail]]];
                    //analyze last time at location
                    if ([imageMetadata objectForKey:@"{TIFF}"]) {
                        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                        [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss"];
                        NSDate *tempDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
                        tempDate = [formatter dateFromString:[[imageMetadata objectForKey:@"{TIFF}"] objectForKey:@"DateTime"]];
                        if ([tempDate compare:latestDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
                            latestDate = tempDate;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }];
        if ([latestDate isEqualToDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0]])
            completionBlock(nil, [NSDate date], photos);
        else
            completionBlock(nil, latestDate, photos);
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        completionBlock(error, nil, nil);
    }];
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that in order to find all the photos taken at the particular location, I have to iterate linearly over all of the photos in the user's camera roll (taking O(n) time). Is it possible to expedite this process by having the system order the photos by latitude and longitude before iterating? What sort of algorithm could minimize the amount of time taken to return the relevant images?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for a spatial index of some sort. Look here in the "Spatial Index" section for a list of possibilities: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should iterate over all photos once, and keep an array of properties from the photos you already processed. This way, next time you iterate, you will only process new photos.

Comment: That is possible. I think what you're saying is cache at least the number of photos (n) that are currently in the user's library, and then next time begin the search at index n (the first new photo in the library). The problem, of course, is that this requires iterating over all photos at least once in the first place. Given the storage capacity on phones now adays, this could potentially mean iterating over thousands of stored photos.

Comment: Cache (n) photos, but be prepared for deleted photos as well. Is the iteration itself taking long time, or is the metadata check that slows down the process? I was thinking more of iterating through thousand of photos every time, but only check the metadata if you don't have a cached copy of the photo.